# Replacing PHP file - file doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, html, apache, caching

I have a weird problem I cannot seem to solve (as a php noob).

I am working on simple php site (no sql involved). Everything was working perfectly till the moment I decided to copy over the files and edit them on another computer. All worked fine on the other computer as well. Then I took the files and copied them to the first computer again. Here came the problem: if I try to open ANY file copied from the second computer, it doesn't show anything, just a blank page. Even if the file was not edited at all on the second computer.

For example my index.php:
1. Copied from comp 1 to comp 2, no edits done
2. Copied from comp 2 to comp 1
3. Opened in the browser -> blank page

What's going on here and how to solve it? Is it some cache that apache is keeping? How to clear it? Both computers with OSX, however the second one was running MAMP, while the first had php/apache/sql set up.

Comment: This is not really a programming issue. Perhaps you should ask at superuser.com.

Comment: I have this problem when I copy down from my staging server, its a permissions issue. Change the owner of the files to be your user, the folders to 0755, the files to 0644, and you'll be fine.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea Seems like that made it! If you want, put this comment as the answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your permissions need to be set up correctly. Do the following:

1. Change the owner of the group to your user
2. chmod 0755 all the directories
3. chmod 0644 all the files

Then you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your permissions are set up correctly.

[Apache Permissions](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/FileSystemPermissions)

Answer (score 0):

The blank page is displaying because Apache is encountering a PHP error somewhere, but is not set to display PHP errors.

Check out what is going on in your Apache error log and work from there. You could also look in the Developer Tools of a browser like Chrome, or use Firebug, to see what response your browser is getting from the server (most likely a HTTP 500 error).

I wouldn't recommend blindly changing ownership on files and directories until you know what is going on.

Comment: If it was a php error the page wouldn't display even before copying it. It was a permission issue as the accepted answer said.

Comment: PHP will generate an error when there is a permissions problem, and report this the Apache error log. The point is that you should determine what your error is, and make the appropriate fix, rather than just making any fix that works.

Comment: Aha, I get it now. How can I enable this logging or where should I look for the log? I am really quite new to all this stuff.